# Error with brew install php@7.4. I cannot solve unexpected /Formula/php.rb error?

Tags: php, homebrew

When i run `brew install php@7.4` i got this error below.

```
Error: php@7.4: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/php@7.4:1: syntax error, unexpected ..
../Formula/php.rb
^~
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/php@7.4:1: unknown regexp options - php
ALT01979:Homebrew hc641j$
```

```
brew install php@7.4.10
```

gives this error below.

```
Error: No available formula with the name "php@7.4.10" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

when i try install php it works but i need to install specifically 7.4.

Comment: try this https://stitcher.io/blog/php-74-upgrade-mac brew update brew upgrade php

Answer (score 2):

homebrew-core does not have an alias for php@7.4, that is why you cannot do `brew install php@7.4`, but you should be able to do `brew install php` to install php 7.4.10

version check test:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.4.10 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2020 18:19:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```